Nisab for Collecting Jizyah From Ahlul Dhimmah
Is there any Nisab for Jizyah on Dhimmis just like there is Nisab for Zakat on Muslim as per Fuqaha?
Note: Prefer To Know Hanbali Fiqh Rulings

Nisab is the minimum amount of wealth that a Muslim must own in order to be obligated to pay Zakat. Zakat is not due from a needy person, rather it is given to a needy person, Nisab is the threshold used to decide whether a person is needy.
Unlike Zakat, Jizyah is taken from a needy person too, provided that he has the ability to earn. The Prophet ﷺ imposed Jizyah of one dinar on every adult male, and Umar ibn al-Khattab imposed a Jizyah of 12 dirhams on the needy and he imposed a higher rate on the rich. If the needy person is not able to earn and hence is incapable of paying Jizyah then the majority do not impose Jizyah on him, while a minority imposes it as a debt.
Nisab is not relevant in the same way in Jizyah, however it is used in some madhabs (who impose different rates depending on a person's financial status) to determine whether a person qualifies as needy.
Ref:

فإن كان الفقير معتملا وجبت عليه الجزية
— Kashshaaf al-Qinaa‘

